# Named rules and local rules

Tags: snakemake

Version 7.3.8

I commonly structure my config.yaml such that public datasets can be automatically downloaded if not present using:

```yaml
# config.yaml
paths:
  vcf: 'path/to/vcf_{chrom}.vcf'
  ...
urls:
  vcf: 'ftp://path_to_vcf_{chrom}.vcf'
  ...
```

```py
# Snakefile
for key, url in config['urls'].items():
    rule:
        name: f'download_{key}'
        output: config['paths'][key]
        params: url=url
        shell: # do download
```

Since the addition of the `name` directive, I can give the rules meaningful names (which is great!).  The issue is I'd like to specify all these download rules are `localrules`.  I can use

```
# Snakefile
localrules:
    download_vcf,
    ...
```

where `download_vcf` is a token, not a string, so I have to manually keep that list up to date with my config.  I'd like to programmatically add each url to local rules. I can do something like:

```py
workflow._localrules.update(f'download_{key}' for key in config['urls'])
```

but I'd like to avoid using the private variable.

Any other recommendations?  Is this something worth a feature request?  Either a method to update localrules or a new directive `localrule` to replace `rule` (similar to `checkpoint`)?  The more I think about it, the more it makes sense to label a rule as local instead of a separate localrules directive.

Comment: For curiosity, is the `name:` directive documented? I couldn't find any reference in the docs. \\ *it makes sense to label a rule as local instead of a separate localrules directive* I think I agree with this.

Comment: Yes, but not [clearly](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html). 
"The name is optional and can be left out, creating an anonymous rule. It can also be overridden by setting a rule’s name attribute."  I noticed it when looking over the [changelog](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html#added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [localrule directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules) has been added as of version 7.25.0